# How to deal with "numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer" when I'm trying to use np.nanmean for finding mean of two array elements?

Tags: python, numpy, mean

I'm trying to assign mean of specific elements inside two arrays without considering NAs in the operation:

```
C [i] = nanmean(A[a, b, c, d], B[aa, bb, cc, dd])
```

The value of `A[a, b, c, d]` is equal to `0.053`, and the value of `B[aa, bb, cc, dd]` is equal to `0.245` in this situation, and they are numpy.float64 type. While executing the code I get this error:

'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

What could be the solution for this???

Comment: Refer to the docs: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html It makes no sense to pass a float as the second argument (axis) for `nanmean`

Comment: See the docs: `numpy.nanmean(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=<no value>)`. In your case, you can only pass `A` or `B` to `numpy.nanmean()`.

Comment: @Samuel but they're not calling it on `A` or `B`, but on two elements of them (one equal to 0.053 and one equal to 0.245). In this case they can pass an array of both elements, like in the (community) answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to [`np.nanmean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html) is the axis alongside the mean is calculated. The axis cannot be a `float`, it has to be and `int`.

If you want the (nan)mean of the elements `x` and `y`, you need to call `nanmean([x,y])`, not `nanmean(x,y)`.
So, you need to change your line to:

```
C [i] = nanmean([A[a, b, c, d], B[aa, bb, cc, dd]])
```